# Validates uniqueness of two columns that references same type of entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called `Conversation` with two attributes `user_1 and user_2` and the following validations:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    2.times { |time| belongs_to :"user_#{time + 1}", class_name: 'User' }
    has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

    validates :user_1, :user_2, presence: true
    validates :user_1_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_2_id,
                                  message: 'Cannot have two conversation with the same user' }
    validates :user_2_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_1_id,
                                  message: 'Cannot have two conversation with the same user' }
end
```

these validations will avoid:

```
user_1  |  user_2              user_1 | user_2  
  1     |    2     and  also      2   |   1
  1     |    2                    2   |   1
```

Could it be possible to add an active record validation to also avoid these?

```
user_1 |  user_2
   1   |     2
   2   |     1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in validator for that but you can use custom validation

```
def validate(conv)
  unless Conversation.where(user_1_id: conv.user_2_id, user_2_id, conv.user_1_id).empty?
    record.errors[:base] << "duplicate conversation exists"
  end
end
```

Note - like all rails internal validations this won't actually guarantee that you'll never get two conversations due to race conditions on database access, for that you'd also need to have a matching unique index in the database, which is going to be database dependent for this type of index (if it's actually possible to do for the database you're using)

Comment: This `ebd` in line 4 is a typo?

Comment: @Daniel - yep, fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can define a scope validation in your Conversation model as

```
scope :between, -> (user_1_id,user_2_id) do
   where(“(conversations.user_1_id = ? AND conversations.user_2_id =?) OR (conversations.user_1_id = ? AND conversations.user_2_id =?)”, user_1_id,user_2_id, user_2_id, user_1_id)
end
```

and use it as:

```
@conversation = Conversation.between(id1,id2)
```

source: [link](https://medium.com/@danamulder/tutorial-create-a-simple-messaging-system-on-rails-d9b94b0fbca1#.zdw4sfw7r)